# Cannot Push Notification from Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

Hello every one I have big problem from firebase push notification console. I am sending notification firebase  console but I never receiving Please help me. I cannot get token to FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); method. Here is my code

app/build gradle

```
  dependencies {

  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my project/ build gradle

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

}
```

My manifest.xml

```
  <service android:name="com.doa.lojisoft.emd.firebaseservice.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.doa.lojisoft.emd.firebaseservice.FirebaseIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

My FirebaseIDService

```
 public class FirebaseIDService  extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

My MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        sendNotification("deneme",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }


    int mNotificationId = 001;
    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody)
    {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(messageTitle);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        notificationManager.notify(632623,notification );


    }
}
```

Comment: Is onMessageReceived() invoked when you push a notification?

Comment: Do you also have the google_services.json file?

Comment: Yes I added google_services.json file and checked items

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate on "*I cannot get token to FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); method*"? You still weren't able to get the registration token?

Comment: I found error. I added  tools:node="merge" line in <application> tag